# Good practice to 'authorize' HTTP-File-Upload to different Server (CDN-like)

Tags: php, jquery

I'm searching for a good practice to authorize HTTP-Uploads using jQuery to a different server.

We currently have a setup of two servers. One for the main Web-Application and one for file-storage. Users need to be able to upload their content to the second server while working with the main application on Server #1.

The key point is the fact, that these uploads must be 'authorized' to prevent users from uploading whatever to the storage server. So if eg. the user clicks on "Upload new profile picture" the Main Application needs to generate a token and submit it to the storage server which then validates it.

Now the question: Is there a more elegant way like injecting the user's session to the storage server or any other best practices?

Comment: Both the storage and the web server should have access to the same sessions. You can use a database which can be reached from both servers as session storage to achieve this.

Comment: So i would submit the session ID from the application-server as metadata with the uploaded file. The storage-server has access to the session and validates the session-id. Correct approach?

Comment: This will work if the session cookie is on the same domain.  You don't want to pass the PHP Session ID around.

Comment: Hmm.. It should be at least the same TLD, yes. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris what is the difference in passing Session ID vs passing key in redis store?

Comment: Session just validates the user is logged in and authorized to upload. "_User A_ can upload". With the redis-solution I'm able to generate a token for each upload-request. So I'm able to control granular actions like "_User A_ uploading _Profile Picture_" and even use a TTL which makes this "Profile Picture uploading permission" valid for eg. 2 minutes.

Comment: @MxAgent Yeah, when both servers are in the same domain it should work..

Comment: @Dexa the session id persists longer than a single use token.  You're exposing a secret key between the user and the remote server leaving the session open to hijacking via man in the middle attacks.

Comment: @Chris OK I agree with that, but this redis thing is also exposed to the man in the middle attack, just timelimit is smaller. Redis is good option, but this can be achieved with both sites accessing same DB (which is same as sharing same session in DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using a token IS the best practice.  If you can setup a common 3rd party server to handle the key verification that would probably be a good starting point and I've included a basic setup for this below.

Simple Version:
Basic Keystore server (redis is more than capable).

Have both the app server and storage server able to authenticate to the redis store.

When a user needs to upload, have the app create a one-time (GUID) key in the redis store.  When you submit the upload include this key in the header.

When receiving the storage request the storage server should pull the key out of the header and verify it exits in the redis store and then clear the key.

You could add any additional data you wanted to in that request as well such as the username, but the key is going to be your authoritative decider.

Comment: And redis is also capable to set a TTL to the records. Brilliant! Fortunately I already use Redis in this project so it would be easy to setup.. I Think, this is a good solution! Thank you!